# generate thumbnail image for youtube video

Tags: video, youtube, drupal-7

I want to generate thumbnail image for youtube video using 'video embed field module'.I'm using 'video embed field module' in drupal 7.I want to create thumbnail for uploaded video.now It created only empty folder as `sites\default\files\video_embed_field_thumbnails\youtube`.I have applied patch file but still not generate thumbnail image [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/thumbnail_image_do_not_appear-2145057-7_0.patch)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't used that module but YouTube Field module, but it doesn't matter both modules should return **videoID**

So for example if you want YT thumbnail image on teaser:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

if ($node->type == 'YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE' && $view_mode == 'teaser') {
krumo($node); // Devel module must be turned on, than you look for videoID in video_embed_field (mine was field_youtube)
// than you create a variable from it:
 $videoid = $node->field_YOUR_FIELD['und'][0]['video_id'];  
//than you create new field with markup called lets say preview_image:

$node->content['preview_image']['#markup'] = 
<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $videoid . '/0.jpg">
}
```

You can do this straight away but i created variable because I needed to do couple of additional things with thumbnail image.